# Generate normal random numbers in float32/16 in-place

Tags: python, random, numpy, scipy

In Numpy/Scipy, how can I generate random numbers from a normal distribution with a specified (float) `dtype`? In my case I need `float32` and `float16`.

Since the array is quite large, I **don't want** to convert the array **after** the sampling.

For example:

```
a = np.random.normal(1e7).astype('float16')
```

does the job but since it need a temporary float64 array it uses 4x the RAM than a direct `float16` sampling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @JChoi [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70218952/1217358), the `standard_normal` method of the `Generator` class in `numpy.random` accepts a `dtype` argument that allows the direct generation of `numpy.float32` samples.  It only accepts `numpy.float32` and `numpy.float64` for `dtype`, so it won't help with `numpy.float16`.

I don't know of a random number generator in numpy or scipy that generates 16 bit floats natively.

To avoid the large temporary, you could generate the values in batches.  For example, the following creates an array of 10000000 samples of `float16` values.

```
In [125]: n = 10000000  # Number of samples to generate

In [126]: k = 10000     # Batch size

In [127]: a = np.empty(n, dtype=np.float16)

In [128]: for i in range(0, n, k):
   .....:     a[i:i+k] = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=k)
   .....:
```

Comment: I accept this answer since and exact in-place operation is not possible and this solution is the best way to generate a big  array of random numbers without using too much RAM.

Answer (score 3):

[standard_normal](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.standard_normal.html) in [Random Generator](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html) now supports `dtype` argument.

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> rng = np.random.default_rng()
>>> rng.standard_normal(10, dtype=np.float32)
array([ 1.0513772 ,  0.471835  ,  0.22101597, -0.5053934 , -0.33512875,
       -0.20794971, -0.2699952 , -1.2080398 , -0.16769128,  1.3502929 ],
      dtype=float32)
```