# In-place operations with a provided memory buffer

Tags: numpy

I want to create a big shared vector of random values with normal distribution.

Here's an example:

```
noise = SharedNumpyArray(num_elements, np.float64).get_np_array()
rg = np.random.RandomState(seed=seed)
noise[:] = self.rg.normal(size=num_elements)
```

If the noise vector is very big it seems inefficient to create a new random vector and then copy it to the shared array.

Is there a direct way to generate random numbers in-place in numpy or do I need to do this in batches?

Comment: Related: [Generate normal random numbers in float32/16 in-place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21999952/generate-normal-random-numbers-in-float32-16-in-place)

Comment: Related but a little old. Maybe things have changed since then?

Comment: I don't know, just linked it for the suggestion of creating by chunks. The API doesn't seem to offer the option, and at first glance there does not seem to be provisions in the implementation. I couldn't find [an issue about it](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues) either, you may consider opening one and maybe a developer will respond (I don't know if there may be some intrinsic limitation in the implementation that would not allow using a pre-existing buffer).

Comment: Creating random numbers is relatively expensive. In comparison the cost of a copy won't be very large. I get less than 10% for a 10^7 length normal random vector. So maybe it's not worth the trouble.

Comment: I'm creating a 1.6 GB vector so that's why I'm worried about memory consumption. I'll initialize the noise vector a batch at a time.